# Dividir String Html

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string

pessoal tenho um HTML com o seguinte código:

```
<div class="page">
...Conteúdo1
</div>

<div class="page">
...Conteúdo2
</div>

<div class="page">
...Conteúdo3
</div>
```

a classe "page" ela cria um fundo como se fosse uma folha A4, para que o conteúdo seja colocado dentro dela, acontece o seguinte, que quando trago o HTML todo em string elas veem em uma string só, só que eu precisava pra cada div de classe "page" gerar uma imagem individualmente, só que não faço ideia de como poderia fazer para separar cada div em uma string diferente.Se alguém puder ajudar.

```
string HTMLemString = RenderizaHtmlComoString("~/Views/Item/Item.cshtml", id);
```

o código acima é onde traz todo o html da pagina.

Comment: Mas como você faz atualmente? Como está o código que gera essa página HTML com as divs?

Comment: coloquei o código na pergunta.

Comment: Ainda está confuso. 
Como você sabe quantas divs você precisa? Por que está chamando sua View dessa forma `RenderizaHtmlComoString("~/Views/Item/Item.cshtml", id);`? 
Provavelmente você vai precisar fazer várias alterações, mas no Item.cshtml você pode criar um loop que cria as divs, desde que informe de alguma forma a quantidade que quer.

Comment: coloca o valor que a string `HTMLemString` fica depois de executar essa chamada `HTMLemString = RenderizaHtmlComoString("~/Views/Item/Item.cshtml", id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

esse código faz a mágica usando expressões regulares

```
var texto = "<div class='page'>...Conteúdo1</div>";
texto += "<div class='page'>...Conteúdo2</div>";
texto += "<div class='page'>...Conteúdo3</div>";
string pattern = "<div class='page'>(.*?)<\\/div>";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(texto, pattern);

foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    MessageBox.Show(m.ToString());
}
```

cada iteração do loop foreach é uma 'page'

Answer (score 0):

Bom, talvez esta soluçao seja um pouco forçada, mas funciona..

```
        string split = "<div class=\'page\'>";
        List<string> div = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(HTMLemString, split, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Where(w=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(w)).Select(s=> split + s).ToList();
```

Comment: atencao as '... podes ter que mudar para " para que coincida com o que tinhas